# Waiting for postgres to become available

Tags: cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I used cookie-cutter to create a app with docker and drf integrated. I followed the steps told in documentation on trying command "docker-compose -f local.yml up" an error occurs which says:-

notwhatsapp_local_postgres | 2023-11-09 08:31:13.433 UTC [31] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bkYDaDaIJc...."
notwhatsapp_local_postgres | 2023-11-09 08:31:13.433 UTC [31] DETAIL:  Role "bkYDaDaIJcufpe..." does not exist.
notwhatsapp_local_postgres |    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"

cookie-cutter version :- Cookiecutter 2.4.0
postgres version :- 11

I am quite new in django and never worked anywhere.

I wanted to postgres to become available

Comment: Most likely there's an issue with the database user's credentials in your  application

Check the Database Settings
Open your project's settings file (usually ```settings.py```) and locate the database configuration.

 Make sure the USER and PASSWORD settings for your PostgreSQL database are correct.

Comment: Please don't share your database credentials, Always be cautious about sharing any sensitive information on the internet, and consider the potential security risks associated with it.